# Issue with Contact Form 7 on Mobile Phones

Tags: themes, forms, contact

I am experiencing an issue with Contact Form 7 not functioning properly on mobile phones on my site: https://www.projectzero.cz/#poptavka. I am seeking assistance to resolve this matter.

To replicate the issue, you can access the contact form by clicking the "Poptávka" button in the website's menu (while on a mobile phone).

The Problem:

- Radio fields cannot be selected on mobile devices.
- File uploads are not functional on mobile devices.

I am currently using the Salient Theme for my website. Through my investigation, I have discovered that activating the "Page Full Screen Rows – Disable On Mobile" setting in the page settings rectifies the problem. You can observe that the form works as expected on this page: https://www.projectzero.cz/poptavka3/#poptavka.

It appears that there is a conflict between the Contact Form 7 functionality and the "Full Page Screen Rows" feature when accessed through mobile devices.

In my attempt to find a solution, I conducted a Google search, but I only came across a ticket from 2017 (https://themenectar.ticksy.com/ticket/1080445/) that mentioned: "This seems like a bug with the fullpage.js Library and a fix is not available yet."

Thank you for your time and attention to this matter.

Best regards,
Romans
​